# Python: property setter with numpy arrays

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, properties

Let's consider the following example:

`point.py`

```
import numpy as np

class Point:
    def __init__(self):
        self._x = np.array([])
        self._y = np.array([])
    
    @property
    def x(self) -> np.ndarray:
        return self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, value: Union[float, list, np.ndarray]):
        self._x = np.atleast_1d(value)

    @property
    def y(self) -> np.ndarray:
        return self._y

    @y.setter
    def y(self, value: Union[float, list, np.ndarray]):
        self._y = np.atleast_1d(value)
```

now, if I do the following:

```
from point import Point

coordinates = Point()
coordinates.x = [0, 5]
coordinates.x[0] = 3
```

When I assign the list the `x.setter` is called but not when I modify an element of the array.

How can I update my code in order to trigger the setter in both?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you really need that: `coordinates.x[0] = 3` acually updates `coordinates._x`? With `coordinates.x[0] = ...` you don't _trigger_ the `__set__`, only the `__get__` of the descriptor, since `[0]` refers to a "method of x".

Comment: show the results of each assignment, and say what's wrong.

Answer (score -1):

```
In [29]: p = Point()
In [30]: x
Out[30]: array([0., 0., 0.])
In [31]: p.x
Out[31]: array([], dtype=float64)
In [32]: p.y
Out[32]: array([], dtype=float64)
In [33]: p.x = [0,5]
In [34]: p.x
Out[34]: array([0, 5])
```

The element assignment works as expected (at least what's reasonable to me):

```
In [35]: p.x[0]
Out[35]: 0
In [36]: p.x[0]=10
In [37]: p.x
Out[37]: array([10,  5])
In [38]: p._x
Out[38]: array([10,  5])
```

I'm not quite sure what's your question.  Is it about the exact mechanism of that assignment?  Did you expect some other behavior?  Nothing in your code tells us what method is being used, though we could add diagnostic prints.

Following python evaluation order, the action is:

```
In [39]: xxx = p.x
In [40]: xxx.__setitem__(0,10)
```

Comment: if you type ```print('setting x')``` in ```@x.setter```, when you do ```coordinates.x = [0, 5]``` it is printed but when you do ```coordinates.x[0] = 3``` it is not. So, I am looking for a solution to have always that printed, i.e. the setter triggered. I am asking this because I need to put some code in the setter

Comment: That diagnostic print should have been part of the original question.  Mutating `_x` cannot be done with the `@x.setter` method.  As I, and others insist, the `[0]=10` step applies to the result of `arr.x`.  The python interpreter performs those as 2 separate steps.

Comment: @mauro There's no hook into the `setter` once you use `[...]` (it isn't even involved at all in this case). If I understand your intension correctly, the only way I see is to wrap a class around `np.ndarray` with a `__setitem__` method that includes the stuff you need and use it for `_x` instead of `np.ndarray` directly (wrap around because I'm guessing that subclassing would be a major pain). But, depending on what you want to do, this can cost you a lot.